# Apache Tika cannot detect file type of input stream while it can file

Tags: java, file, upload, inputstream, apache-tika

I can detect the file type (audio/x-aac) of an aac file using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org) as shown below:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file");
Tika tika = new Tika();
System.out.println(tika.detect(file));
```

But, when I try to detect the file type of an InputStream, the file type of the same file (aac file) is detected as application/octet-stream.

I can convert the inputStream to file, but I do not want to write the file to the disk in order to detect file type. So, how can I detect the file type properly using this approach without writing the file to the disk?

Here is the Controller method that I get file as MultipartFile:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadDocument(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    @RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName {

    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String type = tika.detect(file.getInputStream(), fileName); // -> returns "application/octet-stream"

    // code omitted 
}
```

Comment: Pass the filename to Apache Tika along with the input stream - https://tika.apache.org/2.5.0/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String) - the filename is used as a hint too

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, but it does not make any sense. See my updated code

Comment: Very similar code works fine for me, and very similar code in the Tika unit test suite passes without error. Can you write a standalone junit unit test case which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Can you post your code and then I check it before Unit Test: Thanks in advance...

Comment: `fileName` is just a parameter of method and I am not sure if you refer to the file on a disk location. So, is it possible to detect the file type without writing to disk? Any example please?

Comment: Once again - https://tika.apache.org/2.5.0/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String) - that takes an `InputStream` with the contents in it, and the name of the file it came from. No actual file required

Comment: I had already tried it, but `tika.detect(file.getInputStream(), file.getName());` returns `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue.

For me, a detection with `File` was working and returned `image/png`. With an `InputStream` it returned `application/octet-stream`.

I identified upon thorough debugging of Tika, that **the InputStream I was utilizing had been previously consumed by another function**. Consequently, the InputStream was already positioned at its end. Executing the `inputStream.reset()` function, to reset the InputStream to its start was ineffective.

To resolve this, I had to reload the InputStream **before** invoking the `tika.detect(inputStream)` function to ensure proper detection of the `Content-Type`.